# TeamCity Rest API

Tags: api, rest, teamcity-7.1

How to get the changes of a teamcity build? 
I got the following URL wich list all the build changes and provides a URL using which we can view the changes

```
http://teamcityserver/httpAuth/app/rest/changes?buildType=id:bt2
```

However the given URL "/httpAuth/app/rest/changes/id:433" takes the id which is modification id.

1. How do we get the modification ID?
2. Can we pass the internal build ID or number to get the chnages of a specific build?

Comment: got a way to do it.. First call http://teamcityserver/httpAuth/app/rest/changes?build=id:{BuildId} which will return you an xml containing the REST URL for getting the change details in its href tag "/app/rest/changes/id:433", use that to get the change details. Please suggest if there is some other way to do that

Comment: I'm trying to get the changelog from a range of builds. With the following "app/rest/changes/buildType:(id:20140010)" I only get the latest changelog details...probably because it cannot list all the changelog details if I don't specify a filter. I still don't know how to do this in a range of builds though

Answer (score 0):

Perhaphs  what you need is this:
"https://teamcity.blabla.com/httpAuth/app/rest/changes/buildType:(id:20140010),build:(number:102)" (yes it has a comma in there)

This gives me the changes for a specific build.

Answer (score 0):

First Get the build ID, say it's 88506, then the below request url will list all the changes in the build:-

https://teamcityServer/httpAuth/app/rest/changes?locator=build:(id:88506)