# TeamCity REST API: Who broke the build?

Tags: api, rest, teamcity, build-server, teamcity-8.0

In our office we use a custom [Geckoboard](http://www.geckoboard.com/) to display information about our current build status from our **TeamCity 8** build server.

We display **recent check-ins/changes**, using the following REST query: `http://teamcity.internal.com:8080/httpAuth/app/rest/changes?project:ProjectName&locator=count:10`

We also calculate the **last time the build was broken** with this REST query: `http://teamcity.internal.com:8080/httpAuth/app/rest/builds?locator=project:ProjectName`

However what we've not just been able to do is link the two.

In other words:

- For **recent changes** to determine if the checkin lead to a broken build
- For the **last time the build was broken** determine who made that checkin

Comment: I'm not sure that this is even possible. Depending on your build process and team size, there could have been dozens of commits between builds, and any one of them could have broken the build. Team city's web interface offers a list of candidates for build-breakers.

Comment: Each commit will trigger a build - so can't a broken build be traced back to the commit?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the source code [here](http://svn.jetbrains.org/teamcity/plugins/rest-api/trunk-protocol-8.0/src/jetbrains/buildServer/server/rest/request/ChangeRequest.java) and documentation [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API)

I believe you want something like the following

```
http://teamcity.internal.com:8080/httpAuth/app/rest/changes?locator=build:(status:FAILED,project:ProjectName,lookupLimit:1)
```

This should return the changes associated with the last FAILED build, I haven't tested because I don't use TeamCity.

Also see the following [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088413/teamcity-rest-api) in order to get changes for a specific build.